# Wrapfig alignment argument is not being obeyed

Tags: horizontal-alignment, wrapfigure

So I've been working on a how-to guide and most of the images seem to be aligning correctly withing the `\wrapfigure{}` sections, until I reach this section:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\title{Using Wordpress}
\author{Faris Chebib}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
…
\subsection*{Adding Media Content to Your Post}
    Multimedia refers to images, audio, or videos and can be added to any of your
    posts. Simply select the type of media you wish to add by selecting the
    appropriate icon immediately above the content-entry box (below the title
    input field; see fig~\ref{fig:post_media1}). 

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{media_add1.png}
        \caption{Adding an image (or other multimedia) begins by selecting the
        image upload/insert icon.}
        \label{fig:post_media1}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    Once the image upload icon is selected, a media menu will appear (see
    fig~\ref{fig:post_media2}). This menu allows you to either upload a new image
    (see fig~\ref{fig:select_image_fb})
    or use a previously uploaded image in your post. Other kinds of multimedia
    (such as audio and video) are also available in this menu. To use a
    previously uploaded image, click on the \textit{Media Library} tab and select
    your image (see fig~\ref{fig:media_library}).

    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{media_add2.png}
        \caption{To upload new media, select the \textit{select files}
            option, then upload the file from your computer (see
            fig~\ref{fig:select_image_fb}).}
        \label{fig:post_media2}
    \end{wrapfigure}

  When your image has been selected and has successfully uploaded, you will
    need to make some last adjustments with respect to how the image (or other
    media) is ``layed into'' the post. Once you make these selections, remember
    to click on the \textit{Insert into Post} button (see
    fig~\ref{fig:insert_image}).

    % THIS FIGURE SHOULD ALIGN RIGHT, BUT STAYS LEFT (Same for all {r} following)
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{select_image_fb.png}
        \caption{Selecting an image from your local filesystem.}
        \label{fig:select_image_fb}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    Once the image is inserted into the page (see
    fig~\ref{fig:successful_insert}) you can continue editing the post as usual.
    To adjust any image properties, or to remove the image, simply click on the
    image and click on the appropriate button appearing on the image (the left
    button accesses image editing functions while the right button deletes the
    media).

    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{media_library.png}
        \caption{To select from previously uploaded images, click on the
        \textit{Media Library Tab} and select the image you want to use.}
        \label{fig:media_library}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    To add more multimedia, simply click on the appropriate media icon again and
    continue to upload or add as before.

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{insert_image.png}
        \caption{After uploading the media, you will need to make some final
        adjustments to the style of the media as it is presented onto the post.}
        \label{fig:insert_image}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \subsection*{Formatting Text and Adding Hyperlinks}
    \textit{Hyperlinks} or \textit{Links} refers to the interactive text on a web
    page. This is the text that one can click on in order to open another web
    site. To add a link, simply highlight the text you would like to turn into a
    link and click on the add link button (just bellow the upload buttons). Once
    selected, be sure to add the full \textit{URL} (Uniform resource locater;
    \textit{eg:} \texttt{http://example.com}). This will turn the selected text
    into a link to the \textit{URL} you specified.

    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{successful_insert.png}
        \caption{A successfully inserted image in a Blog Post.}
        \label{fig:successful_insert}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    To format your text, simply select the text you would like to format by
    clicking on the text and dragging the cursor until the selection matches the
    text you would like to select. Once that text is selected, click on the font
    format you would like to apply (on the top of the content box). For example,
    you may click the \textbf{B} icon in order to make the font bold,
    \textbf{like this} or you may select the \textit{I} icon in order to make
    italicized text, \textit{like this}.


    \subsection*{Publishing}
    Finally, the publish box on the upper-right of the entry allows you to set
    the date when the entry will be published. Alternately, if the entry is not
    ready for public viewing, you may set the status to \textit{draft} and change
    the visibility. You may also use the \textit{preview} button to produce a
    sample preview of the page you are about to publish. It is always good
    practice to create a preview of the entry before publishing a public version.

    \section*{Adding a Static Page}
    When you want to add content which isn't time-sensitive, such as an
    \textit{About} page or a location information page, you will want to add a
    \textit{Page}. To add a page, log into the wordpress administration panel and
    select \textit{Pages}$>$\textit{Add New}. Once selected, you will be
    presented with the add page view of the admin interface
    (fig~\ref{fig:add_page}).

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{AddNewPageScreen.png}
        \caption{The static post entry page. This page allows users to add a static
        page which never expires.}
        \label{fig:add_page}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    When adding a static, you may also want to add some multimedia. The method of
    adding media is the exact same as the method described above. Remember, the
    only difference between adding a Blog Post and a Static Page is that the
    static page is \textit{not} time-sensitive. 

    \section*{Adding Events}
    Events are similar to blog posts, but in addition to being time-sensitive,
    also include a location entry stating where the event will take place. It is
    important to list the location when adding an event, even if the location is
    a virtual space (such as an Internet chatroom or webpage). To add an event,
    click on the \textit{Add Event} link on the left-column
    (fig~\ref{fig:add_event}).

\end{document}
```

The output of all subsequent figures has them aligned left, rather than the left, right, left… sequence I intended. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so I think I figured out what's causing the problem. It seems that there was an issue following the `\ref` command with `\begin{wrapfigure}` and the alginment environment was being carried over. I simply moved a sentence after the end of that parenthetical statement and things seems to be dandy.

Comment: I suggest you write up a separate answer to your original question, keeping in mind that it may be helpful to future readers experiencing a similar problem to yours. Self-answers (even if they are accepted) are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.